# Google Login stopped working in debug and started working in production as soon as I added app signing key as Client ID in Google Cloud

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication

I have a Unity Android app, which is using [this asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/google-login-ios-android-94517) to log in with Google. Google login worked fine in debug, but not in production (the app downloadable from Google Play). To resolve this, I added the Google Play app signing key as a Client ID in Google Cloud Console (so now I have 2 Client IDs, one for debug and one for production). As soon as I did that, Google login stopped working in debug mode, but started working in production.

Things I've tried to make login work in debug (none of them worked):

- Deleting the Client ID using the Google Play app signing key, so only the Client ID using the upload key certificate remains
- Changing the Google Play app signing key and signing my app with it
- Deleting and reinstalling the app
- Using a different Google account to log in

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your free tier is expired. The client ID still has the free credit thus it is working.

Comment: My free tier isn't expired. Also, if that would be the case, I'd expect it to not work in production, but the opposite is true.

Comment: If I didn’t read it wrong, You mentioned that it worked fine in production with client ID

Comment: Yes, exactly. I don't get your point, sorry